# Solve recurrence relation $T(n) = 64T(\frac n8) − n^2\log{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence relation:

$$T(n) = 64T(\frac n8) − n^2\log{n}$$

Now the solution manual says it's not solvable as $f(n)$ is not positive when compared with master method though we can see that:

$$T(n) = 64T(\frac n8)+n^2(\log{n})^-1$$

So, we can see that $log_b(a) = 2 = k$, so we have **CASE II**. Since $p=-1$, then we have $O(n^2\log\log{n})$, but again solution says it's not solvable, what do you think please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

The formal recurrence

$$
T(n) = a^2 T\left(\frac na\right)-n^2 \ln n
$$

can be handled as follows

$$
T\left(a^{\log_a n}\right) = a^2T\left(a^{\log_a \frac na}\right)-n^2 \ln n
$$

Calling now $\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T\left(a^{(\cdot)}\right) $ and $z = \log_a n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}(z) = a^2 \mathcal{T}(z-1)-a^{2z}z\ln a
$$

with solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)  = a^{2z}\left(c_0 -\frac 12 z(z+1)\ln a\right)
$$

now to recover $T(n)$ we go backwards with $z = \log_a n$